# It seems like there is an error and there is not

Tags: android, android-studio

why the red lines are under drawable folders (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) like in image in the link below.

I do clean and rebuild project and still seeing the red lines under folder.
I do not know if there is a problem or not but it seems its a bug in android studio because the app is running without any fails.

anyone has any idea what is going on??

[drawable folders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htI4W.png)

Comment: `I do not know if there is a problem or not`, well, does it build ? can you run the app ?

Comment: Yes I can build and run the app successfully

Comment: then it's just a bug with android studio, either that or you don't have correct images in your higher resolution folders